# java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: BUT the URL is fine and the method works for other GET Requests

Tags: java, http, servlets, get

I wrote the following Code:

```
public String sendGet(String url) throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnection httpClient = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        httpClient.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = httpClient.getResponseCode();
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(httpClient.getInputStream()))) {
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
            return response.toString();
        }
}
```

And it works very fell for my GET Requests, but not for this :
[https://www.lichess.org/api/user/{USERNAME}](https://www.lichess.org/api/user/%7BUSERNAME%7D)

If I send it, I get the following Error:

PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: {Expected Response}

The expected response is in the error msg.

I send this GET request to an external API from lichess.org and I tryed the request with Postman and in my browser and it works. The problem must be in my code. (Using Java 8 and java.net) It's strange that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Do you know what to do ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't send the brackets. I just wanted to show that i insert a username here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is specific case. URL [https://lichess.org/api/user/{georges}](https://lichess.org/api/user/%7Bgeorges%7D) in browser does not work as well while https://lichess.org/api/user/georges does (without {}). Same with your code snippet.

Comment: I don't send the brackets. I just wanted to show that i insert a username here

Comment: @SmittyWerben Should I take it that https://lichess.org/api/user/georges  does not work in your environment? If it always works, could you post the one of the *actual URL* that does not?

Comment: Yes, that URL is not working. Other URLs to this API are working. Getting games (https://lichess.org/api/games/user/{username}) etc. is working, but the player information (https://www.lichess.org/api/user/{USERNAME}) is not. It seems strange to me. Do you have an idea ? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, I made a spelling mistake in a call bevor that method. I'm so sorry for wasting your time, this was dumb. But thank you very mutch for trying to help me <3

Comment: @SmittyWerben lol. It's okay. Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

Curly brackets in URLs are not allowed.

They are sometimes used for variable names in URI templates, and your example URL looks indeed like that. So "{USERNAME}" likely needs to be replaced by a ... user name, and when doing that, the brackets would need to be removed.

Comment: I don't send the brackets. I just wanted to show that i insert a username here.

Comment: Well, then please supply the precise URL you *are* sending.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a spelling mistake in a call to this method. Thanks for trying to help me <3. My bad.